Error occured from python joblib.load : persistent IDs in protocol 0 must be ASCII strings In GCP cloud run
Overall: I tried to build BERT model with Cloudbuild and Cloudrun. I saved the model (parameter) and metadata (labels) at the GCP Cloud Storage. But, I encountered the error from load metadata.bin file by joblib.load(). My metadata.bin file contained UTF-8 characters but joblib.load expected ASCII characters. And default protocol is 4 in my version, but the error messages indicates the protocol was 0.
Related Dependencies: python 3.8.0, joblib 1.1.1 (I've already tried to upgrade recent version), google-api-core==2.19.1, google-auth==2.32.0, google-cloud-core==2.4.1, google-cloud-storage==2.18.0
My Effort: I already tried two cases.

Tried at local. In this case, downloading both model.bin and metadata.bin files at GCP Cloud Storage works.
Tried at docker. In this case, loading metadata.bin file and model.bin file at dockerized container also works.
Tried at Cloudbuild not using Cloud Storage but build image locally by containing metadata.bin and model.bin. It also works!

Error Details:
`
  File "./src_review/model_server.py", line 70, in load_bert_model
      metadata = joblib.load(metadata_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load
      obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
      obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1210, in load
      dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1244, in load_persid
      raise UnpicklingError(
          _pickle.UnpicklingError: persistent IDs in protocol 0 must be ASCII strings`

My Code:
`
 def load_bert_model(config: argparse.Namespace):
      bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
      model_blob = bucket.blob(model_file)
      metadata_blob = bucket.blob(metadata_file)        

      local_model_path = '/tmp/pytorch_model.bin'
      metadata_path = '/tmp/meta.bin'    

      print(f"Downloading model to {local_model_path}")

      model_blob.download_to_filename(local_model_path)        
      log.info(f"Model downloaded to {local_model_path}")
      metadata_blob.download_to_filename(metadata_path)
      log.info(f"Metadata (label) downloaded to {metadata_path}")

      metadata = joblib.load(metadata_path)
    ...`

From GCP official Documents. I also used the codes below for upload.
`
def upload_directory_with_transfer_manager(bucket_name, source_directory, workers=1):
    bucket = create_bucket_if_not_exists(bucket_name)
    directory_as_path_obj = Path(source_directory)
    paths = directory_as_path_obj.rglob("*.bin")

    file_paths = [path for path in paths if path.is_file()]

    relative_paths = [path.relative_to(source_directory) for path in file_paths]

    string_paths = [str(path) for path in relative_paths]

    print("Found {} files.".format(len(string_paths)))

    results = transfer_manager.upload_many_from_filenames(
        bucket, string_paths, source_directory=source_directory, max_workers=workers, skip_if_exists=False
    )

    for name, result in zip(string_paths, results):
        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            print("Failed to upload {} due to exception: {}".format(name, result))
        else:
            print("Uploaded {} to {}.".format(name, bucket.name))

`
Expected Cause: I think cloud run config is quite different from my test environments. But I could not expected the main causes.
++ I tried case # 3 at My Efforts. It is more clear that main problem is at Cloud storage uploading or downloading.
Thanks for your efforts!

This problem solved at now. I did not any updates but when I retried it, it works!
